# What language should I use to create a simple text-formatting application online?

Tags: text, formatting, blogs, richtextediting

I want to make a page for a website that will let the user create a blog post, and want them to be able to graphically edit the formatting, like paragraphs and styles, then convert this to html. Is there a way to do it in PHP? Do I need to use Javascript or Ajax or something?

Comment: Do some more research.  What you're wanting is client-side, and thus not reasonably possible with PHP.  Javascript and Flash can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP (if you want dynamic behavior) with [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) (on the client side) will do the job. Have a look at [the demo](http://www.fckeditor.net/demo). Another good editor is [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: I took a brief look at both and TinyMCE's UI looks much more modern.

Comment: I prefer FCKeditor which is more advanced though. I've used both.

have a look at the trends: http://www.google.com/trends?q=fckeditor%2C+tinymce
and a more elaborate comparison: http://webtecker.com/2008/04/02/fckeditor-vs-tinymce/

Comment: A really simple and easy-to-use service is NicEdit (nicedit.com). It's hosted on their website, so all you have to do is add two lines of javascript.